# Shift data from one column to another column in same table

Tags: c#, sql, project, dot

I have a Database table named major.
I want to shift items or data(selective) from one column(A) to column(B) in the same table Major
Please help me out
Give me a sql query

Comment: Hello and welcome to the community. Here you can ask for advice and help when you showing what you already have done. The community won't be doing job for you or writing code for you.

Answer (score 1):

update major set column_b = colmn_a